# How to hide the edit/delete/view buttons on Laravel Nova?

Tags: laravel, resources, laravel-nova

So I'm trying to hide buttons in Laravel Nova resource. But I dont know what i can add to the code.

Those buttons:

[image]

Comment: Is there code that you have attempted?

Comment: @J_D not realy, the only thing i've figured out is how to hide the resurce in navigation with this:  
`public static $displayInNavigation = false;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution first you create a policy via artisan command:
 **php artisan make:policy ModelNamePolicy --model=ModelName**

then you get a file in app/Policies/ModelNamePolicy.php

```
public function view(User $user, InstructorOverview $instructorOverview) {
    return false;
}
```

And you can just return false in functions view, create, update, delete, restore, forceDelete.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this for a Lens this can be done by overriding the method  serializeForIndex in the model related to the lens, so for instance in the lens itself we have a uriKey method

```
// In your lens file - in my case BuildingStatsLens
/**
 * Get the URI key for the lens.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function uriKey()
{
    return 'building-stats-lens';
}
```

and in the model, in my scenario Building model, we'll have this code

```
// In your model - in my case Building
/**
  * Prepare the resource for JSON serialization.
  *
  * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
  * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Collection  $fields
  * @return array
  */
public function serializeForIndex(NovaRequest $request, $fields = null)
{
  $serialized = parent::serializeForIndex($request, $fields);

  if ($request->lens && $request->lens == 'building-stats-lens') {
      // If a lens is being viewed 
      $serialized = array_merge($serialized, [
          'authorizedToView' => false,
          'authorizedToUpdate' => false,
          'authorizedToDelete' => false,
          'authorizedToRestore' => false,
          'authorizedToForceDelete' => false,
          'authorizedToReplicate' => false,
      ]);
  }

  return $serialized;
}
```

This way view, edit, delete and replicate options will be hidden.